# Caffe runs same program on same GPUs allows different batch size

Tags: gpu, caffe

I have 2 computers with the same GPU Quadro M4000, both 8GB. I run the same train.prototxt on both computers, one can run batch size=5 (as my image size is big), but the other can't and gives the error

```
syncedmem.cpp:51] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (2 vs. 0)  out of memory
```

Anybody knows why?

Comment: Maybe something else is running on it? Can you check the memory usage before running them.

Comment: There isn't anyone else using it. I always clear the memory before I run

Comment: please add a bit more information about the 2 machine? If both are exactly same and u clear memory every time it should work on both..

Answer (score 0):

Check with following command:

`nvidia-smi`

It will show you the process running on GPUS. Comparing on both machine's statistic you can check why it is not working on other machine. May be on one GPU there are some other program consuming the memory/

Comment: I always do nvidia-smi before I run caffe, and kill the process that is running on GPU.

Comment: how about reducing batch size to 4?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the other GPU is out of memory. try to reduce the batch size (for example: `batch size = 1`)